# NodeJS: How do I force "raw" mode in net.createServer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, telnet

Hopefully this question finds you all well and does not seem overly stupid :)

I have been working on a MUD (game server) for quite a while and now I am trying to add some more advanced features.  I am using a nifty package called [Ranvier Telnet](https://github.com/RanvierMUD/ranvier-telnet) to handle the legacy Telnet/MUD clients.  My problem is that when that package binds a port with net.createServer() on a port OTHER than 23, it changes something in the socket behavior (linemode perhaps?).  When the socket 'data' event fires, I want each character individually (raw mode) and not only when a user sends CR/LF.

It works as would like when binding port 23, but that is not always an option.  I would like to have this same functionality extend to arbitrary port numbers.  Am I missing something obvious?  I don't see anything in the NodeJS documentation (looking at the options object in net.createServer).